# how to modify the confirmation email in Ubercart?

Tags: emails, theming, ubercart

I'm trying to modify the format and text of the confirmation email in Ubercart and I don't know from where....can anyone give me hint?
for example including some images or custom links in some parts of the email, quit the horrible yellow background of the site name , etc, etc...
I'm using Drupal 6

Here's what I'm receiving at the moment...
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to override the file 'uc_order-customer.tpl.php' found in the ubercart module. The way you do this is:

You need to copy **two** files from sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_order/templates
The files to copy are **uc_order.tpl.php** and **uc_order-customer.tpl.php**

Then just edit uc_order-customer.tpl.php to your liking.

Comment: Thanks! I just copied uc_order-customer.tpl.php file to my template and wondered why it didn't worked.

Comment: Glad to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally if you want to build multiple templates you can copy the uc_order.tpl.php to your theme's templates directory and create a new template called something like uc_order-customer2.tpl.php where customer2 can be any name you choose.

Then implement a hook to identify the new templates:

```
function hook_uc_invoice_templates() {
  return array('customer2');
}
```

Make sure the 'customer2' is the same as that part of the template file name.

This way you can make unlimited e-mail templates and keep the original customer template intact.

Also note that you can choose the template you want sent in the conditional actions predicate.